# How to iterate a list of lists and change element values?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a list of lists:

```
game = [['X', 'O', 'O'], ['', '', 'O'], ['', '', '']]
```

And I would like to change all the values:

- If the element is 'X' then set to 1.
- If the element is 'O' then set
  to 2.
- If the element is "" (nothing) then set to 0 (zero).

The output would be:

```
game = [['1', '2', '2'], ['0', '0', '2'], ['0', '0', '0']]
```

I can iterate, like this:

```
for list in game:
  for element in list:
    ...
```

but to change the elements in my list of lists it's another story, I can create a new list with append, but I get something like `[1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: Are you looking to **predefine** your factorization, e.g. `X -> 1`, `O -> 2`, etc (almost always work you *don't* want to do manually). Or would *any* consistent factorization work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a dictionary and a list comprehension:

```
>>> game = [['X', 'O', 'O'], ['', '', 'O'], ['', '', '']]
>>> d = {'X': '1', 'O': '2', '': '0'}
>>> [[d[x] for x in row] for row in game]
[['1', '2', '2'], ['0', '0', '2'], ['0', '0', '0']]
```

Comment: The most pythonic solution

Comment: Why to create a new list if we can update the existing one?

Comment: @mad_ It depends on the requirements. For small enough lists using a list comprehension is usually the most concise and fast method.

Comment: @mad_, Because time complexity is identical and memory may not be an issue. [And, if memory is relevant, another data structure would be more appropriate.]

Answer (score 2):

Lots of great answers already.  I'll toss in a one liner using `map()` just because it's fun:

```
[list(map(lambda x: {'X':'1', 'O':'2', '':'0'}.get(x), i)) for i in game]

# [['1', '2', '2'], ['0', '0', '2'], ['0', '0', '0']]
```

Explanation: `map()` essentially applies a function on top of the object `i` being passed, which are the sub-lists of game.  In this case we want to apply `.get(x)` from the scoring dictionary on each mark (`x`) within the sub-lists (`i`) in `game`.  Combined with list comprehension it gives you all transformed scores as a new `list` of `list`s.

Comment: I like this better than my answer using `map()` (more readable). You could also do `[list(map(lambda x: {'X':'1', 'O':'2'}.get(x, '0'), i)) for i in game]` to default a `'0'` value if the nested lists contain any value other than `'X'` or `'O'`

Comment: Agreed, though in this context I lean towards explicitly defining `{'': '0'}` as `['X','O','foo']` will also return `['1','2','0']` which might not be the intended result.  We're not sure what OP might want in case of an undefined x, which will *then* fall under the use case of `.get(x, default_value)`.

Comment: No question that making default assumptions can cause problems. OP may be developing a game of "tic, tac, foo, bar, baz" for all we know :)

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have a list of answers that is working toward exhausting all possibilities for converting the values of a list of lists based on a simple mapping, it seems like we would be remiss not to include a solution that uses `map()`. So here it is:

```
game = [['X', 'O', 'O'], ['', '', 'O'], ['', '', '']]

nums = [list(map(lambda x: '2' if x == 'O' else '1' if x == 'X' else '0', row)) for row in game]
print(nums)
# OUTPUT
# [['1', '2', '2'], ['0', '0', '2'], ['0', '0', '0']]
```

Comment: See the better `map()` answer from @Idlehands.

Answer (score 0):

Try enumerating the list:

```
game = [['X', 'O', 'O'],['', '', 'O'],['', '', '']]

for list in game:
  for num,element in enumerate(list):
    if element == "X":
      list[num] = "1"
    if element == "O":
      list[num] = "2"
    if element == "":
      list[num] = "0"

print(game)
```

Comment: This is work for relatively less data but would become messier if we have to map tons of values. Use dict or other data structure which is more elegant

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward with [numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/)

```
import numpy as np
game = np.array(game)

game[game=='X'] = 1
game[game=='O'] = 2
game[game==''] = 0

print(game.tolist())
# [['1', '2', '2'], ['0', '0', '2'], ['0', '0', '0']]

print(game.ravel().tolist())
# ['1', '2', '2', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0']
```

Comment: I think it is an overkill to use `numpy` here where no vectorized manipulation are required. You are creating a numpy array from existing list -> doing numpy operations->converting numpy to list again.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping dict and iterate the list( without creating a new list)

```
d={'X':'1','O':'2','':0}
for i in game:
    for idx,value in enumerate(i):
        i[idx]=d.get(value, str(value))

print(game) #[['1', '2', '2'], ['0', '0', '2'], ['0', '0', '0']]
```

If you want to create an entirely new list

```
d={'X':'1','O':'2','':0}
new_list=[]
for i in game:
    temp=[]
    for idx,value in enumerate(i):
        temp.append(d.get(value, str(value)))
    new_list.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

`new_list = []
for list in game:
    new_sublist = []
    for item in list:
        ...
        new_sublist += new_item
    new_list += new_sublist`

This should get you a 2D list with your approach using loops only.

Answer (score 0):

I would define rules in a dictionary and get the values and use default 0 for empty strings.

I used list comprehension as well.

only list comprehension:

```
new_game = [[rules.get(item, 0) for item in li] for li in game]
```

Using a helper function:

```
game = [['X', 'O', 'O'],
['', '', 'O'],
['', '', '']]

rules = { 'X': '1', 'O': '2' }

def update_list(li):
  return [rules.get(item, 0) for item in li]

new_game = [update_list(li) for li in game]

print (new_game)

# [[1, 2, 2], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0]]
```